# PP_ALIGN.CENTER do nothing

Tags: python, python-pptx

The below line code do nothing:

```
row.cells[0].text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignement = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
```

It also does not throw any error.

Am I doing something wrong there ?

Below is the reproducible example :

```
for row_idx, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    row.cells[0].text_frame.paragraphs[0].alignement = PP_ALIGN.CENTER
```

The goal of the above code is to center first cell of each row. But for now they keep being aligned on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly likely to be `alignment`, not `alignement`.

The latter is an attribute with no usefulness.

I have got table cell alignment to work in my md2pptx (https://github.com/MartinPacker/md2pptx)package. (And, no, this is not intended to be an advert for that. Feel free to browse the code.)